# SQLite figuring out which constraint was violated

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

Suppose I have a table declared like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
name_eng TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
name_ger TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

I'm working with the C/C++ SQLite API.

When a constraint violation occurs while trying to enter a new record, how can I figure out what caused the violation? The goal is to relay correct error feedback to the user without having to write code to check correctness of input.

Edit: I'm currently checking for errors using `sqlite3_errstr(sqlite3_errcode(db))`. This only tells me when a constraint violation occurred.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `sqlite3_errmsg()` following an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3_errstr()` describes the error *code* in English while `sqlite3_errmsg()` describes the error itself.

Example using the `sqlite3` client (which uses `sqlite3_errmsg()`):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles(
   ...> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
   ...> name_eng TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
   ...> name_ger TEXT UNIQUE
   ...> );
sqlite> insert into articles values(1,'a','b');
sqlite> insert into articles values(1,'a','b');
Error: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
sqlite> insert into articles values(2,'a','b');
Error: column name_ger is not unique
sqlite> insert into articles values(2,'a','a');
Error: column name_eng is not unique
sqlite> insert into articles values(2,null,'b');
Error: articles.name_eng may not be NULL
sqlite> insert into articles values(2,'b','b');
Error: column name_ger is not unique
```